# pick a random item from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, bots, discord

*I am making a bot that can respond to my messages.*

If i send `Hi!` to the bot, it will answer With `Well, hello there!`. I was just wondering, what do I do to give the bot multiple choices of answers? **Is there a way to pick a random item from a responses array using JavaScript?**

Comment: Could you spend some time first to show the relevant code you have and what you have tried to make it work?

Comment: Have you looked at `Math.Random`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use Math.random * the length of the array, rounded down, as an index into the array.

Like this:

```js
var answers = [
  "Hey",
  "Howdy",
  "Hello There",
  "Wotcha",
  "Alright gov'nor"
]

var randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];

console.log(randomAnswer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[_.sample](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sample)** method in lodash:

```js
var responses = ["Well, hello there!", "Hello", "Hola", "Yo!", "What’s up?", "Hey there."];
console.log(_.sample(responses));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways:

Method 1:

- Use Math.random() function to get the random number between(0-1, 1
  exclusive).
- Multiply it by the array length to get the numbers
  between(0-arrayLength).
- Use Math.floor() to get the index ranging
  from(0 to arrayLength-1).

> const answers = [
> "Hey",
> "Howdy",
> "Hello There",
> "Wotcha",
> "Alright gov'nor"
> ];
> const randomlyPickedString=answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
> console.log(randomlyPickedString);

Method 2:

- The random(a, b) method is used to generates a number between(a to b, b exclusive).
- Taking the floor value to range the numbers from (1 to arrayLength).
- Subtract 1 to get the index ranging from(0 to arrayLength-1).

> const answers = [
> "Hey",
> "Howdy",
> "Hello There",
> "Wotcha",
> "Alright gov'nor"
> ]    ;
> const randomlyPickedString=answers[Math.floor(random(1, 5))-1];
> console.log(randomlyPickedString);

For ease of understanding the code, I have written created an extra variable(randomlyPickedString). You can use the code without it too.

Answer (score -1):

There's no JavaScript "command" that allows you to do this. But what you can do, is pick an integer at random from 0 to the length of the array, and get the array of responses at that index:

`var response = responses[ parseInt( Math.random() * responses.length ) ];`

A more concise way to do this is:

`var response = responses[ Math.random() * responses.length |0 ];`

where `| 0` indicates the bitwise-or with 0, which in this case just turns a floating point number (`Math.random()` returns values from 0 to 1) into its lowest integer

Comment: Instead of parseInt why not Math.floor?

Comment: that works as well, but I'm taking the examples for what he might end up starting with and what he might see online. If someone is advanced enough to know about Math.floor, they're probably advanced enough to know about tricks like `|0`

Comment: I disagree, rounding is taught in grade school but bit operations are taught in college.

Comment: actually, they haven't taught me about bitwise even in the university...

Answer (score -1):

You would first need an array of possible responses. Something like this:

```
var responses = ["Well hello there!","Hello","Hola!"];
```

You can then use the `Math.random` function. This function returns a decimal < 1, so you will need to convert it to an integer.

```
var responses = ["Well hello there!","Hello","Hola!"];
var responseIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```

Also, use the modulus (`%`) operator to keep your random number within the confines of your array indexes:

```
var responses = ["Well hello there!","Hello","Hola!"];
var totalResponses = responses.length;
var responseIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) % totalResponses;
```

Finally, lookup your random response in the array:

```
var responses = ["Well hello there!","Hello","Hola!"];
var totalResponses = responses.length;
var responseIndex = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1) % totalResponses;
var response = responses[responseIndex];
alert(response);
```

Comment: Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length) is enough to generate a random index.